# Surface area integral, derived from two independent line element

Tags: integration, metric-spaces

Say I have a line element defined as

$$
(ds)^2=g_{\mu\nu}dX^\mu dX^\nu
$$

I can define a line integral as follows:

$$
L=\int ds=\int\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}dX^\mu dX^\nu}
$$

That I can parametrize as follows:

$$
L=\int\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dX[\tau]^\mu}{d\tau} \frac{dX[\tau]^\nu}{d\tau}}d\tau
$$

---

On the other hand, the surface area integral is defined as follows $A=\iint \sqrt{\det g_{\mu\nu}}dudv$.

I would like to derive this result in the spirit of the line integral derivation by replacing $du$ and $dv$ by two independent line elements.

$$
(ds_1)^2=g_{ab}dX^a dX^b\\
(ds_2)^2=g_{cd}dX^cdX^d
$$

I can now write:

$$
\begin{align}
A&=\iint ds_1ds_2\\
&=\iint \sqrt{g_{ab}dX^a dX^b}\sqrt{g_{cd}dX^cdX^d}\\
&=\iint \sqrt{g_{ab}dX^a dX^b g_{cd}dX^cdX^d}
\end{align}
$$

If I now parametrize the surface in terms of u and v, I get:

$$
A=\iint \sqrt{g_{ab}\frac{dX[u,v]^a}{du} \frac{dX[u,v]^b}{du} g_{cd}\frac{dX[u,v]^c}{dv}\frac{dX[u,v]^d}{dv}}dudv
$$

I am not able to see how this term reduces to $\sqrt{\det g_{\mu\nu}}$.

---

For the record, I am aware that the definition of the surface area integral is $A=\iint |\vec{r}_u \times \vec{r}_v| dudv$, but here I am trying to understand if one can get a sensible result by integrating over two independent line elements.

Comment: So part of the reason this doesn't make sense is because $ds_1$ and $ds_2$ aren't a basis over the surface

Comment: They are exactly the same line element as opposed to an expression such as $dx, dy$ wherein the $x,y$ point to distinct basis directions (orthonormal or whatever is not necessarily important here just that the $s_1$ and $s_2$ are copies of each other).

Comment: The deeper spirit of your question however still exists, "how do i generate that basis $ds_1$ and $ds_2$ properly, and then show that integrating it equals integrating the square root of the determinant of the metric and reduces to the cross product in $\mathbb{R}^3$?"

Comment: In particular a concept called the Gram Matrix is generally used to create volume forms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix, which relies on an inner product. I wonder if that euclidean inner product is replaced with the inner product induced by the metric $g_{ij}$ if that recovers the formulas you have here